# C# contains method not allowing me to pass it a string

Tags: c#

Trying to check to see if a username exists in a list.  The contains method that comes with the list class is not accepting a string as a parameter, despite examples online showing that that's exactly what you pass it.

I keep getting the following error when I try to build:

```
Error:  The best overloaded method match for
   'System.Collections.Generic.List <TCPServer.User>.Contains(TCPServer.User)' 
        has some invalid arguments.

if (this.tcpClients.Contains(usr.UserName.ToString()))
                    {
                        //Append _number to name
                    }
```

Anyone see why I cannot pass the 'Contains' method a string?

Comment: because it doesn't take a string

Comment: The contains would work if your collection was a collection of strings, but your list is a list of TCPServer.User objects.  Think of it like this:  You can't compare your object to a string, so how would a generic contains know how to find your match?  If you can use linq, use the solution below from Selman22, otherwise use a loop to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of `Users`, so the `Contains` method expects a `User`.

If you wanna check for `Name` you can use  Linq:

```
if(tcpClients.Any(x => x.UserName == usr.UserName))
```